# TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases sequence item 2: expected string or Unicode, int found

Tags: django, django-models

I have the following models.py

```
from django.db import models
import datetime

class Build(models.Model):
    build_name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    parts = models.ManyToManyField('Part')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.build_name

class Part(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    cost_usd = models.DecimalField(5, 2)
    type_of = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    supported_builds = models.ManyToManyField(Build)

    def __unicode__(self):
         return self.name

class OrderBuild(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Build)
    custom_parts = models.ManyToManyField(Part)

class PriceCache(models.Model):
    price = models.DecimalField(4, 2)
    time_fetched = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now())
```

I've tried commenting each of the lines one by one and rerunning, and there is no one line that seems to cause this bug. The only time it synced successfully was when I commented everything out in the model classes.

Does anyone know what is causing this bug, and how I can fix it?

Comment: can you update the question with the stacktrace?

Comment: There is none that I can see. This is all it returns. http://i.imgur.com/OdrMt1k.png How do I get a trace?

Comment: in `__unicode__`, you might have `return self.__` which is returning an `int` type - replace that with `return '%s'% self.__`

Comment: Just did that. No change.

Answer (score 4):

Check the lines

```
cost_usd = models.DecimalField(5, 2)
# ...
price = models.DecimalField(4, 2)
```

by modifying them to

```
cost_usd = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
# ...
price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=2)
```

The signature of model fields are like

```
field(verbose_name=None, name=None, ...)
DecimalField(verbose_name=None, name=None, max_digits=None, decimal_places=None, **kwargs)
```

Thus your code have `verbose_name` and `name` of the fields incorrectly set to integer numbers.